# Where does one obtain the most widely accepted Bitcoin/Euro exchange rate?

Tags: exchange-rate

I want use Bitcoin to make a purchase from a private seller in another country. The good which I want to purchase is priced in Euros, so I need a Bitcoin/Euro conversion rate which both of us must accept for the moment when the Bitcoin is transferred.

Answer (score 2):

[Bitstamp](https://bitstamp.net/) is reputable and generally accepted in the context you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It would be reasonable to take a weighted average of all major exchanges, such as [BitcoinAverage.com](https://bitcoinaverage.com/markets#EUR).